# Efficiency on a 64-bit platform: pointer vs 32-bit array indexing

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, pointers

In one of his keynote, Andrei Alexandrescu, suggests that, on a 64-bit platform, using 32-bit array indexing is faster than using raw pointer:

Page 16: http://www.slideshare.net/andreialexandrescu1/three-optimization-tips-for-c-15708507

On his Facebook account, he is more precise and says: "Prefer array indexing to pointers (this one seems to reverse every ten years).".

I have tried many things to find a difference, but I have not managed to build any program that shows this difference. Knowing Andrei, I would not be surprised that the difference is no more than a few percent, but I would be glad if anyone find such an example.

Here is a test I have done. I choose n = 5000, large enough to get a decent timing and small enough so that everything fits in the L1 cache. I loop a few times so that the CPU frequency rises.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  const int n{5000};
  int* p{new int[n]};

  // Warm up the cache
  for (int i{0}; i < n; i++) {
    p[i] += 1;
  }

  for (int j{0}; j < 5; j++) {
    {
      auto start_pointer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      for (int* q{p}; q != p + n; ++q) {
        ++(*q);
      }
      auto end_pointer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto time_pointer = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
                              end_pointer - start_pointer)
                              .count();
      std::cout << " Pointer: " << time_pointer << std::endl;
    }

    {
      auto start_pointer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      for (int* q{p}; q != p + n; ++q) {
        ++(*q);
      }
      auto end_pointer = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto time_pointer = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
                              end_pointer - start_pointer)
                              .count();
      std::cout << " Pointer: " << time_pointer << std::endl;
    }

    {
      auto start_index_32 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      for (int i{0}; i < n; i++) {
        p[i] += 1;
      }
      auto end_index_32 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto time_index_32 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
                               end_index_32 - start_index_32)
                               .count();
      std::cout << "Index 32: " << time_index_32 << std::endl;
    }

    {
      auto start_index_32 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      for (int i{0}; i < n; i++) {
        p[i] += 1;
      }
      auto end_index_32 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto time_index_32 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
                               end_index_32 - start_index_32)
                               .count();
      std::cout << "Index 32: " << time_index_32 << std::endl;
    }

    {
      const std::size_t n_64{n};
      auto start_index_64 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      for (std::size_t i{0}; i < n_64; i++) {
        p[i] += 1;
      }
      auto end_index_64 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto time_index_64 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
                               end_index_64 - start_index_64)
                               .count();
      std::cout << "Index 64: " << time_index_64 << std::endl;
    }

    {
      const std::size_t n_64{n};
      auto start_index_64 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      for (std::size_t i{0}; i < n_64; i++) {
        p[i] += 1;
      }
      auto end_index_64 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto time_index_64 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
                               end_index_64 - start_index_64)
                               .count();
      std::cout << "Index 64: " << time_index_64 << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  delete[] p;

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the kind of result I get on my machine (core i7). All I get is "noise".

```
 Pointer: 883
 Pointer: 485
Index 32: 436
Index 32: 380
Index 64: 372
Index 64: 429

 Pointer: 330
 Pointer: 316
Index 32: 336
Index 32: 321
Index 64: 337
Index 64: 318

 Pointer: 311
 Pointer: 314
Index 32: 318
Index 32: 319
Index 64: 316
Index 64: 301

 Pointer: 306
 Pointer: 325
Index 32: 323
Index 32: 313
Index 64: 318
Index 64: 305

 Pointer: 311
 Pointer: 319
Index 32: 313
Index 32: 324
Index 64: 315
Index 64: 303
```

Comment: Considering the article did you mean to tag this questions as `C` or `C++`?

Comment: The talk mention C++ in the title, but the question refers to concepts that are already in C. Moreover, Andrei's talk stick to the C part of C++. This is the reason I have tagged it with C. But I have added C++ for a broader audience.

Comment: That's all the confirmation I was looking for. I wanted to insure the pointer issue was applicable to basic arrays and not *vectors*, etc..

Comment: could you share some testing code you made? Results, some more information.. It could be a good startup.

Comment: Maybe this is one of those things where measured efficiency is deeply linked to the core revision of the CPU.  For instance, I have seen the non-temporal store instructions perform three times as slow on a higher generation Xeon CPU.

Comment: I'd think this would take some serious benchmarking to prove, and the results would likely be extremely hardware- and compiler-dependent.

Comment: The only answer here that makes sense to me is "ask Andrei".  Personally I think it's a mistake to try and "out think" a modern compiler.  Optimize algorithm and data structure and memory structure choices.  Let the compiler sort out the nitty gritty - gcc is honestly better that this old assembly language warhorse anyway.

Comment: @InsideLoop, I'm curious at the way you perform variable initialization (with braces rather than the = operator). Is it just a stylistic preference or are there any possible gains from doing it this way?

Comment: @BlueStrat: It is called braced-initialization, and is a C++11 feature. One of its advantage is that it prevents narrowing. int n{8000000000}; won't compile as 8000000000 does not fit in 32-bit. int n{3.14159} won't compile either.

Comment: @InsideLoop, Oh I see, seems like a smart choice then.  Thanks for the enlightment!

Comment: @StephenG, I've sent him an email. If he has some time to reply, I'll share it here.

Comment: I don't think this is true as a general rule. Not only the compiler has major impact, but also the language (this is C++; it might differ for C), but even more, of course the CPU (instruction set, pipeline, etc.) and system architecture. Far too broad to handle here.

Comment: BTW, are you using VS 2015 to run that test?``std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`` doesn't work like you'd expect on 2012/2013.

Comment: @Chuck: I am using gcc, clang and the Intel compiler on OSX. The STL is the libstdc++ or libc++.

Comment: Sometimes, when the array index is 32bit and *signed*, it results in annoying sign extensions all over the place.

Comment: @harold: I am curious about that. Doesn't the x86_64 has an operation to add a 32 bit signed integer to a pointer? In C, people use 32-bit signed integer for array indexing and I've never heard nor measured a performance problem.

Comment: `new int[n]` does not initialize the ints; your code goes on to cause undefined behaviour by doing `+=` on them

Comment: I can't believe you initialized `int`s with braces...

Comment: @Mehrdad. Once you have done int n = 8000000000; a few times with a compiler that does not issue a warning, you start to prefer braces :-)

Comment: @InsideLoop: Whoa wait, I didn't know that makes a difference here. What's the difference between using braces and (a) parentheses, (b) assignment for `int`?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Brace initialization prevents narrowing because of the standard. Other kind of initialization don't.

Comment: @InsideLoop: Holy cow, I did not know! Thanks for that!!

Comment: @InsideLoop there is no operation to add a 32bit register to a 64bit register, regardless of signedness. And usually the compiler can figure out that sign extension is not necessary, or at least lift it out of a loop, but you can force it to generate a `movsxd` in some cases. Zero extension is usually free because any operation on the 32 bit register will already have zero-extended it.

Comment: You should do `*q+=1` to have equivalence with the integer case.

Answer (score 41):

The problem with low-level advice like this (even coming from Andrei Alexandrescu) is that it ignores the fact that compilers optimize.

Modern compilers optimize so aggressively (and, in general, successfully) that it really becomes a mug's game to try to second-guess them. On the whole, writing clear, readable code will help you, your colleagues and your compilers analyze the code. And I honestly believe that is the best general advice that can be given.

One of the well-known optimizations which modern compilers use is the conversion between index- and pointer-based loops. In the particular case of your benchmark, with most optimization settings, gcc will compile both the pointer-based and the 32-bit-index-based loop to the same assembler output.

In the following, I replaced the chrono stuff with `++sentry` where `sentry` is a `volatile` in order to reduce the code size. The assembly output corresponds to:

```
for (int* q{p}; q != p + n; ++q) ++(*q);
++sentry;
for (int i{0}; i < n; i++) p[i] += 1;
```

Compile with `-O2`, this produced the following: (`%rdi` and `%ebp` were still initialized from the loop which populated `p`)

```
        movq    %rdi, %rdx
        cmpq    %rcx, %rdi
        je      .L10
.L16:
        addl    $1, (%rdx)
        addq    $4, %rdx
        cmpq    %rcx, %rdx
        jne     .L16
.L10:
        movl    sentry(%rip), %eax
        movq    %rdi, %rdx
        addl    $1, %eax
        movl    %eax, sentry(%rip)
        testl   %ebp, %ebp
        jle     .L8
.L14:
        addl    $1, (%rdx)
        addq    $4, %rdx
        cmpq    %rdx, %rsi
        jne     .L14
.L8:
```

You can see that there is no difference at all between the loops at `.L16` and `.L14`.

Different optimization settings produce different results, of course. With `-O3` the loops are vectorized using SIMD instructions and Duff's device, but again are almost identical. clang does this optimization at `-O2`

None of that denies the point being made, which is that the compiler may need to work harder to prove that a pointer which is being written through cannot modify arbitrary memory.

But in this case, as in many cases, the loop index is a local variable and the loop is simple enough that the compiler can fully analyze it, thus allowing strength reduction, unrolling, and vectorization; whether the control variable is a pointer or an index is then irrelevant.

---

A more interesting example (possibly) is a loop over two arrays where the base elements are different sizes. Given the following two functions:

```
void d2f_ptr(float* out, const double* in, int n) {
  for (auto lim = out + n; out < lim;) *out++ = *in++;
}
void d2f_idx(float out[], const double in[], int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) out[i] = in[i];
}
```

gcc (v5.3.0, -O2) does produce different loops and the index-based loop is one instruction shorter:

```
d2f_ptr(float*, double const*, int):    d2f_idx(float*, double const*, int):
        movslq  %edx, %rdx                      xorl    %eax, %eax
        leaq    (%rdi,%rdx,4), %rax             testl   %edx, %edx
        cmpq    %rax, %rdi                      jle     .L16
        jnb     .L11
.L15:                                   .L20:
        addq    $4, %rdi                        pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
        addq    $8, %rsi                        cvtsd2ss (%rsi,%rax,8), %xmm0
        pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0                    movss   %xmm0, (%rdi,%rax,4)
        cvtsd2ss -8(%rsi), %xmm0                addq    $1, %rax
        movss   %xmm0, -4(%rdi)
        cmpq    %rdi, %rax                      cmpl    %eax, %edx
        ja      .L15                            jg      .L20
.L11:                                   .L16:
        ret                                     ret
```

But change the `double` and `float` to objects whose sizes no longer permit the use of the Intel chip's indexed addressing mode, and the compiler once again converts the index-based code to a pointer-based variant.

Here the code is essentially the same as before, but the double has been padded to 48 bytes:

```
struct Big { double val; char padding[40]; };
struct Small {
  float val;
  Small& operator=(const Big& other) {
    val = other.val;
    return *this;
  }
};

d2f_ptr(Small*, Big const*, int):       d2f_idx(Small*, Big const*, int):
        movslq  %edx, %rdx                      testl   %edx, %edx
        leaq    (%rdi,%rdx,4), %rax             jle     .L26
        cmpq    %rax, %rdi                      leal    -1(%rdx), %eax
        jnb     .L21                            leaq    4(%rdi,%rax,4), %rax
.L25:                                   .L29:
        addq    $48, %rsi                       pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
        addq    $4, %rdi                        addq    $4, %rdi
        pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0                    cvtsd2ss (%rsi), %xmm0
        cvtsd2ss -48(%rsi), %xmm0               addq    $48, %rsi
        movss   %xmm0, -4(%rdi)                 movss   %xmm0, -4(%rdi)
        cmpq    %rdi, %rax                      cmpq    %rax, %rdi
        ja      .L25                            jne     .L29
.L21:                                   .L26:
        ret                                     ret
```

---

It's possibly worth adding that for compilers, it is not necessarily more difficult to analyze which object a particular pointer write will modify. [**Edited**: There was a quote from Alexandrescu here, but it wasn't as relevant as I thought, so I removed it leaving this section to be mostly a strawman.]

In fact, if a pointer is only directly assigned to once, and all other modifications are through increment and decrement operations (including `+=` and `-=`), then the compiler is totally within its rights to assume that the pointer always points within the same object. If some additive modification of the pointer were to overshoot into some other object, that would be Undefined Behaviour and the compiler can discard that possibility. It's easy enough to track assign and inc/dec operations in a flow graph, so in cases where the pointer could have been replaced with an index expression, it is quite possible for a compiler to figure that out and thus know that other objects are not being randomly mutated by writes through the pointer.

Comment: Thanks. Could you think of an example where the assembly could differ?

Comment: I'd say you're more likely to see differences if you have more complex code, where the compiler can't determine the index value (e.g. a function that takes an index as input, and that the compiler can't/won't inline), where the index will need to be sign extended to 64-bits. But then that's not trivially replaceable with a pointer anyway.

Comment: I understand it as "prefer array indexing over pointer arithmetic whenever you can. May not make any difference. If it ever does, array indexing is going to be faster". Just like the `++i`vs. `i++` or `'\n'` vs. `"\n"` etc.

Comment: @mehrdad: It was copied from the OP. I just removed the extra vertical space so it fit on my screen better.

Comment: @jarod42: Thanks. In the actual test, I didn't commit that embarrassing mistake. I deleted the comment and added the information to the answer.

Comment: @insideLoop: in my last edit yesterday, I inserted an example whuch might exhibit slightly faster performance with an index loop. ( The loop reduces a vector of doubles to floats.) I didn't try benchmarking but the disassembly looks like it should be faster. But it is quite possible that somwone could find an example which exhibits the opposite behaviour. In any case, I can't believe the difference would ever be significant.

Answer (score 11):

His (Andrei Alexandrescu) reasoning seems to be based on the fact that using a register for a pointer variable is generally harder for compiler since a pointer could be pointing a to global data. But I don't see anything specific to 32-bit array indexing (To my reading, the slide wasn't quite clear if he was actually referring to 32-bit arrays or array indexing 32-bit systems)

[From the horse's mouth:](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/three-optimization-tips-for-c/10151361643253920/) (yes, it's a link to his Facebook account  :)

> Minimize array writes
>
> To be faster, code should reduce the number of array writes, and more
> generally, writes through pointers.
>
> On modern machines with large register files and ample register
> renaming hardware, you can assume that most named individual variables
> (numbers, pointers) end up sitting in registers. Operating with
> registers is fast and plays into the strengths of the hardware setup.
> Even when data dependencies--a major enemy of instruction--level
> parallelism - come into play, CPUs have special hardware dedicated to
> managing various dependency patterns. Operating with registers (i.e.
> named variables) is betting on the house. Do it.
>
> In contrast, array operations (and general indirect accesses) are less
> natural across the entire compiler-processor-cache hierarchy. Save for
> a few obvious patterns, array accesses are not registered. Also,
> whenever pointers are involved, the compiler must assume the pointers
> could point to global data, meaning any function call may change
> pointed-to data arbitrarily. And of array operations, array writes are
> the worst of the pack. Given that all traffic with memory is done at
> cache-line granularity, writing one word to memory is essentially a
> cache line read followed by a cache line write. So given that to a
> good extent array reads are inevitable anyway, this piece of advice
> boils down to "avoid array writes wherever possible.

He also seems to suggest, it's *general* suggestion rather than it's *always* faster to use array indexing(from the same post):

> A few good, but less known, things to do for fast code:
>
> Prefer static linking and position-dependent code (as opposed to PIC, position-independent code).
> Prefer 64-bit code and 32-bit data.
> **Prefer array indexing to pointers (this one seems to reverse every ten
> years).**
> Prefer regular memory access patterns. Minimize control flow.
> Avoid data dependencies.

Comment: Seems like a lost opportunity to point out the other big advantage, the less you write arrays the less bugs you have.  Two for the price of one, what's not to like?

Answer (score 8):

I wrote an email to Andrei Alexandrescu and he was kind enough to reply. Here is his explanation:

"In order for the speedup to be visible, you need to exploit the ALU's capability of running either two 32-bit operations or one 64-bit operation in one cycle. Not every benchmark will show a speedup."

I understand it as "SIMD instructions process more data per cycle with 32-bit data than 64-bit data". I have yet to find a benchmark (that doesn't contain any array of integers) where it makes a difference. But I assume it's going to be difficult. Andrei used to work for Facebook where every single percentage was worth getting.

Comment: That doesn't apply to scalar operations though, there is no microarch that splits an 64bit ALU that way. Well P4E sort of did it (P4 did it with 32bit) with its weird staggered adders, but it didn't have that result - the throughput was the same for either size. Nothing else does any splitting for 64bit scalar operations. Some SIMD operations on 64bit integers were split at times, for example PADDQ on Pentium M, and SIMD operations on 128bit registers were often split (P3, PM, K8, Bobcat) and later it was the 256bit ones that got split (AMD)

Comment: @harold: It really seems that this "optimization tip" from Andrei should be ignored in my programs. Anyway, as I can't reproduce it for the time being, I'll just ignore it.

Comment: Well, that nails it.  Optimization advice from Andrei should be taken with a boulder of salt.

Comment: Making data structures that *store* `uint32_t` array indices instead of pointers saves space in 64bit mode.  This helps you get the benefit of having more registers and a better ABI in 64bit mode without paying the cost of larger pointers causing more cache misses, in cases where it's viable.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly an answer, but too complex for a comment:

Your test is a really limited test of pointer arithmetic vs. array indexing; in the simple cases, with optimization turned up *every* compiler worth its salt will produce the same assembly for both. When the index variable isn't otherwise used, the compiler is perfectly free to switch to pointer arithmetic in the assembly, and it's equally capable of switching pointer arithmetic back to array access if it so chooses.

Best example I can come up with is from a few years ago (and probably isn't consistent from compiler to compiler, architecture to architecture, etc.). I was playing around with (for learning purposes) two versions of code that basically amounted to an array copy operation:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < copycnt; ++i) {
    x[i] = y[i];
}
```

vs.

```
while (copycnt--) {
    *x++ = *y++;
}
```

I'm guessing there was some complicating factor (or compiler optimizations have changed, since last time I tested something like this at high optimization it compiled to the same assembly), but even though the compiler could trivially convert the first case to the second (and theoretically save a register, avoid offset load and store instructions in favor of direct load and store instructions, use a `testl` for 0 instead of a `cmpl` of two values, for the small cost of adding one decrement instruction), the compiler instead chose to compile code that would be approximated roughly by:

```
const ptrdiff_t diff = y - x;
decltype(*x) *const end = x + copycnt;
while (x < end) {
    *x = *(x + diff);
    ++x;
}
```

That's probably superior to either of the "normal" versions of the code if you count number of registers needed in the loop, number of instructions in  the loop (assuming load at fixed register offset is a combined instruction as it is on x86 machines, rather than `add` then direct load), etc., and the compiler definitely thought so, since it chose this version over straightforward pointer arithmetic (which any compiler could do here).

But when I compiled the straightforward pointer arithmetic code, the compiler couldn't figure out the relationship (probably due to some complicating factor not present in this simplified version; I know neither `x`, `y` or `copycnt` was used again, so it wasn't a matter of preserving original values), and compiled to more or less exactly what I'd given it, two pointers, incremented independently.

My theory is that the use of an index gave the compiler context for what I was doing; it wasn't two unrelated pointers, it was two "arrays" being accessed via a common index, and it knew how to improve the compiled code for that pattern. The pointer arithmetic was "do what I say" without giving context for "what am I trying to do" and the compiler couldn't figure it out, so it didn't optimize it.

Anyway, obviously just anecdotal, but I figure the example is representative of the more complex possibilities; array indexing gives the compiler more information about the "higher logic" of what you are doing, where pointer arithmetic says what to do but not why it's being done, so the compiler has a harder time optimizing, which may explain the recommendation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting comment which explains the: prefer indices over pointers. I am still puzzled with the: prefer 32 bit integers over 64 bit integers for indices.

Comment: @InsideLoop: Might be an x86-64 specific recommendation. Several instructions in x86-64 weren't fully extended to 64 bits in the move from x86. If I'm reading [the relative addressing docs](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf#page=41) correctly, address displacements are still limited to 4 byte displacements in some circumstances, so if the compiler might need to handle 8 byte displacements, it wouldn't be able to use a single instruction to load from an offset.

Comment: Yes but that applies only to constant offsets, which array indexes usually are not.

Answer (score -1):

This type of optimization is only at metal level and you should ignore them. I would focus more on other things that actually introduce *noise* to your tests.

**[ISSUES]**

1. pointer assignment is done with `++(*q)` , whereas for integral types its faster to do `(*q)++` , but at any rate you should be consistent with the int32/int64 tests and do `*q+=1`.
2. pointer tests compute everytime in your loop the end pointer, you should do it once `int * ep{p+n}` and check against that.
3. In integer tests you should not use `<` but `!=` for termination evaluation.
4. Running just five times will not give enough schematics.
5. You must set cpu affinity
6. You should make more loops and account only the last one
7. You should have a system where compiler has been compiled to the metal
8. You should not "warm up the cache the way you do it"
9. You should randomize your input.

I have changed you code, and you can retrieve it from [here](http://pastebin.com/k5hJq7W1) .

You should compile with:

`g++ -O3 -march=native --std=c++11 -o intvsptr`

and launch with

`taskset 0x00000001 ./intvsptr`

and then you should get consistent results.

> Pointer: 4396  Pointer: 4397 Index 32: 4395 Index 32: 4394 Index 64:
>   4394 Index 64: 4395
>
> Pointer: 4395  Pointer: 4397 Index 32: 4397 Index 32: 4395 Index 64:
>   4393 Index 64: 4396
>
> Pointer: 4395  Pointer: 4397 Index 32: 4396 Index 32: 4394 Index 64:
>   4394 Index 64: 4396
>
> Pointer: 4396  Pointer: 4397 Index 32: 4397 Index 32: 4395 Index 64:
>   4394 Index 64: 4395
>
> Pointer: 4395  Pointer: 7698 Index 32: 4471 Index 32: 4422 Index 64:
>   4425 Index 64: 4407
>
> Pointer: 4399  Pointer: 4416 Index 32: 4394 Index 32: 4393 Index 64:
>   4399 Index 64: 4412

Precision of this tests should be at last digit, but normally one should do an extensive stat analysis.

I have pasted the last few runs of one execution, but having done multiple , I think it is safe to say as far as this microbenchmark permits that **pointer arithmetic is faster** or in the worst case *just a bit slower* .

At any rate , you can **ignore this type of *tips* that may have mattered ages ago but not with current compilers**.